# Como detectar diatónicamente la anchura de la pagina y modificar una clase del CSS

Tags: javascript, css3

Tengo el siguiente codigo en mi archivo javascript:

```
if (screen.width < 801) {
  document.getElementById("nav-links").className += "overlay-menu";
} else {
  document.getElementById("nav-links").className += "";
}
```

Esto hace que al principio si que aplique o no la clase al CSS según el tamaño, pero si redimensionas la pagina luego, no se aplica el cambio de estilo CSS.
Como puedo hacer para que se aplique al redimensionar?

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con *diatónicamente*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La solución mas sencilla seria usar `@media` en css para que de esta forma no necesites si quiera usar `javaScript`.

Un ejemplo podría ser el siguiente:

```
@media (min-width: 801px) {
  .overlay-menu {
       //Estilos del overlay menu
  }
}
```

En el `div` de `html` añadirias la clase y esta solo se ejecuta a partir de los `801px`

```
<div id="nav-links" class="overlay-menu"><!-- Contenido --></div>
```

Comment: Genial! He conseguido que me funcione correctamente! Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: @ErikPastorRios si funciona y la respuesta es correcta¿Podrías aceptarla como valida dándole click al "check"?

Answer (score 2):

El objeto window tiene el evento `onresize`, puedes usarlo para que cada vez que se cambie el width del navegador se vuelva a preguntar si quieres que tu estilo CSS se aplique o no.

Podrías implementarlo así:

```
object.onresize = function(){
    if (screen.width < 801) {
       document.getElementById("nav-links").className += "overlay-menu";
    } else {
       document.getElementById("nav-links").className += "";
}
};
```

Comment: Gracias a todos por la ayuda! He conseguido solucionarlo por medio de media queries y gracias a las herramientas de desarrollo de Chrome he podido comprobar los estilos que me fallaban al principio!

Muchas gracias por la ayuda y los consejos!

Answer (score 0):

La primera vez que cambia si funciona bien y cuando redimensionas no se aplica porque la condición solo se aplica una vez a menos de que pongas un listener que cuando cambia el tamaño de la pantalla haga X cosa o mejor aún, ese tipo de cosas las haces con CSS y no necesitas de ningun listerner o algo por el estilo, se hace con media querys

Comment: Hola Luis, bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a realizar el [tour] para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y ganar tu primera medalla! Por otro lado, si te fijas en el resto de respuestas a esta pregunta, lo habitual es dar una pequeña explicación/corrección y además añadir el código al que hace referencia. Mas info en [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Los compañeros ya han aclarado que es mejor que lo hagas con css, de todas formas es posible que tengas que hacerlo por JS si lo que buscas es afectar a otras clases ( tipo .overlay-menu .main{} )
En ese caso, si lo haces por JS, esta linea es inutil y no está haciendo nada:

```
 document.getElementById("nav-links").className += "";
```

Si lo que quieres es quitarle la clase deberias hacer:

```
if (screen.width < 801) {
document.getElementById("nav-links").className += "overlay-menu";
} else {
document.getElementById("nav-links").classList.remove("overlay-menu");
}
```

Por otro lado, no estas comprobando si #nav-links ya tiene la clase puesta, por lo que si lo haces con .onresize como propone el compañero te va a empezar a añadir la misma clase una y otra vez.
Si no lleva mas clases que esa, quitale el "+"

Comment: Gracias a todos por la ayuda! He conseguido solucionarlo por medio de media queries y gracias a las herramientas de desarrollo de Chrome he podido comprobar los estilos que me fallaban al principio!

Muchas gracias por la ayuda y los consejos!